# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c1da68)

Tags: android

I'm getting exception threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c1da68) without any stacktrace making my application to close forcefully.I'm not getting solution for mentioned problem.If anybody knows how to get rid of above mentioned problem please let me know.

Comment: There has to be a stack trace. See if you have any filter on logcat.

Comment: Try to find in which part of code you are getting the and exception and the enclose the code in a try catch block. In this way, you will get complete stacktrace.

Comment: @ Rohit5k2 I don't have any filter still not getting stack trace

Comment: what were you doing that such a thing happen !!!
what i can guess is OUT OF MEMORY problem.
once i was working on a map application. i had to show lots of markers on it. when the number of items grow, i had such a problem! the app close without any stack trace !
when ir educe the size of markers, the problem gone

Comment: Did you develop a native part in your app?

Comment: @suns9- Yes I'm developing native part in my Application

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the data, cache of the app. and then run again.
2. Try restarting adb.